# Unusual SQL server timeout expired

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2012, timeout

I've been experiencing some issues with my website. Every day during busy times on my website (300-400 concurrent users), users start to receive a lot of "Timeout Expired" error messages. The web pages hang and timeout for usually 2-3 minutes every few hours.

In mist cases the error messages received are just "Timeout expired", but sometimes they come with a little more regarding max pool size. I'm not sure if it is the pool size or if that is just a symptom of the timeouts.

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server session database. ---> 
System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired. 
The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. 
This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
```

Here is an example of what my DB function looks like:

```
Public Function StoredProcedureDataSet(ByVal strStoredProcedureName As String, ByVal cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand) As DataSet
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = strStoredProcedureName
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
    Dim objDA As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim objDataSet As New DataSet
    Try
        conn.Open()
        objDA.SelectCommand = cmd
        objDA.Fill(objDataSet)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        StoredProcedureDataSet = objDataSet
        conn.Close()
        cmd.Dispose()
        objDataSet.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function
```

I make sure the connection is opening inside the Try and closed in the Finally, so there is no way I'm leaving connections open.

I am using SQL server for the sessions instead of the application pool, so I'm not sure if it's linked to that. Please note that I have other applications using the same database and they will continue to work without any issues while the timeouts are happening on the busy app, so this is maybe hinting that it's something to do with the sessions.

Based on suggestions from other posts, I tried changing the max pool size to 1024, but taht didn't help. Maybe it's too low?

```
    <sessionState mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=*********;Initial Catalog=*********;User ID=*********;Password=*********;Max Pool Size=1024;" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: i guess there may be issue in `Max pool size` which you added. try this one and check `Max Pool Size=100`

Answer (score 0):

I timeout can be produce by a long running sql, i notice that you are using a store procedure with no parameters to select data, how big is the dataset it returns?

If it's big enough it will produce  timeout. If that's the case you have to introduce where parameter to handle a query with a smaller result set.